# Angular renders unnecessary space

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a members component which has all single member component in it.

If I use members component as static shown below, problem dont occurs

```
<div class="row bg-light justify-content-center py-4">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <h3 class="font-weight-light pb-2">Members</h3>
    <div class="row">
<!-- Repeating div -->
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-2"> 
        <div class="card px-0 ">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000495007683-zg65ko-t500x500.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body p-2 text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title mb-1">Name Surname</h5>
            <p class="card-text mb-1">Title</p>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion ion-logo-linkedin text-dark mx-1 h3"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion ion-logo-github text-dark mx-1 h3"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="ion ion-logo-twitter text-dark mx-1 h3"></span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- Repeating div -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But if I use repeating div as a component, problem occurs

```
<div class="row bg-light justify-content-center py-4">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <h3 class="font-weight-light pb-2">Members</h3>
    <div class="row">

      <app-member></app-member>
      <app-member></app-member>
      <app-member></app-member>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
I couldnt figured out why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
<app-member style="display: contents;"></app-member>
```

however it is not supported in every browser.

You can also use:

```
<app-member class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-2"></app-member>
```

of course you should remove this classes within the component

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra tag `<app-member>` wrapping your component which is not having the required styling. Here `<app-member>` tag is your component selector defined in your component.

[image]

Giving an appropriate styling to the `<app-member>` tag will resolve the issue for now, but I will suggest you to style parent of `<app-member>` with appropriate Display property and then use css selector to style `<app-member>` for this particular instance so the styling wont affect other `<app-member>` tags in your applications.

Its really common issue developers face regarding component styling. :-)

Letme know, I can help you with this component styling if required.